# mysqli error - fetch array expects parameter to be 1, string given

Tags: php, mysqli

Why won't this work?
I have used a tutorial to do it.

```
// FETCH DATA FROM INPUT FIELD
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($db2, $_POST['user']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($db2, $_POST['pass']);

  // CHECK ALL FIELD HAS BEEN FILLED UP
 if ($user && $pass) {

       // QUERY FROM DATABASE
  $query= mysqli_query($db2, "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='".$user."'");
  $checkuser= mysqli_num_rows($query);

   // CHECK IF USERNAME EXIST ON DATABASE
  if($checkuser != 1) {

    // I'LL BE SETTING A VARIABLE IF YOUR DOESN'T EXIST
   $error = "Username doesn't exist in our database!";
  }

   // FETCHING PASSWORD IN DATABASE WHERE USERNAME COINCIDES
 while  ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user)) {
   $checkpass= $row['password'];


    // CHECK IF ENTERED PASSWORD MEETS THE USERNAME PASSWORD
   if ($pass== $checkpass) {

     // IF ALL OKAY SET SESSION
    setcookie("user", $user, time()+7200);
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (60 * 60 * 60);
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit();
   } else {

     // SET VARIABLE THAT'LL SHOW IF USER PASSWORD IS INCORRECT
    $error = "Incorrect password!";
   }
  }
 } else {

  // SET VARIABLE IF ALL FIELD ARE NOT FILLED UP
 $error = "Please enter a username and password.";
 }
}

?>
```

Comment: It should be `while  ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {` , You are passing a string which is `$user` in this case.

Comment: Now im getting this error: 

Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sql/login.php:11)on line 52

http://pastebin.com/gGuwgqUa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
 while  ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user))
```

with

```
while  ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
```

You get header error because this piece of code

```
 setcookie("user", $user, time()+7200);
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (60 * 60 * 60);
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Should be before any output

Comment: Where should I put it then? I get the exact same error wherever I put it in the file.

Comment: Is the code you posted complete or you omitted some pieces?

Comment: <title>*****</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom.css">
<div style="text-align: center;">
 
<form action="" method="post" id="loginForm">
<span class="input">Username: <input type="text" name="user" maxlength="16"></span>
<span class="input">Password: <input type="password" name="pass">
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
 
is an input. So put your php code before it.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb, when you want to use header(...); you must make sure that php hasn't started outputting anything yet.

It means : no echo, print_r, var_dump ... but also keep in mind that php files output everything that is not between . So  at the end. I'm talking about ALL the files that might be included before the actual header(...);

It seems though you'r outputting something on line 11 of login.php:11